# automatically add object id on subdocument when updating in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Document:

```
[{
   _id: "58aaf5f87fa9df48753fa04b",
   username: "test",
   stores: [ ]
}]
```

I want to add new objects in the stores element. IS there any way to automatically add a new _id for each new object I add? I'm using the version 2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`mongodb` native driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) not, it won't add an `_id` to sub-documents for you.

But if you use [`mongoose-odm`](http://mongoosejs.com/) it will add the `_id` automatically on an array of sub-documents.

If you use `mongodb` native driver you can just add and initialize a `_id: ObjectID()` field before save it:

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
const doc = {
   _id: new ObjectID(),
   username: "test",
   stores: [ ]
}
doc.stores.push({ _id: new ObjectID(), value: '...' });
```

Comment: I tried the third option but for some reason it says ObjectId is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BatteryDetails {
    /**
     * The batteryId of the Battery.
     */
    private String batteryId;
public BatteryDetails() {
        batteryId= new ObjectId().toString();
    }
}
```

This line (`batteryId= new ObjectId().toString();`) creates a `objectId` for the sub document.